# "request.getParameter" return "-1" for non-existing URL parameters

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts-1

I have used following, in a JSP file to retrieve URL parameter.This JSP file represent a web page with a form which I am validating with Struts validator.

```
<% String tempVal= (String)request.getParameter("parm");%>
```

When the form initially loads, the `tempVal` parameter's value is `null` if there is no URL parameter with the name `parm`.
Then I submit the form with some invalid data in the form, and the come to the same page(After hitting `Validate` method in the `ActionForm` class) with validate error messages.

But this time the `tempVal` parameter's value is `-1`.

Following is my `Validate` method in the `ActionForm` class.

```
@Override
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    ActionErrors errors = null;
    errors = super.validate(mapping, request);
    String temp2 = request.getParameter("param3");
    if(temp2 == null){
        errors.add("some Error");
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Any reason for this behavior ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your URL parameter must be in string format if you are trying to receive request at other form.

But if your Url parameter are not in string format then I will recommend to use **getAttribute**

Here same happening, Because you are trying to getParameter from Object and ten converting to String which give you -1.

First page

```
  //first page: first.jsp
  <% request.setAttribute("PAGE", "param");%> 
  <jsp:forward page="/second.jsp"/>
```

and second.jsp:

```
  <%=request.getAttribute("PAGE")%>
```

**It is crucial to know that attributes are not parameters.
The return type for attributes is an Object, whereas the return type for a parameter is a String. When calling the getAttribute(String name) method, bear in mind that the attributes must be cast.**

Additionally, there is no servlet specific attributes, and there are no session parameters.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Casting to "String" is not necessary, I understand.But **String tempVal= request.getParameter("parm");** is the way to get URL parameter.Still i can not understand the reason for this behavior.